# how to modify store name in dokan multivendor plugin using filters?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, dokan

in developing a wordpress plugin
i that, i want to modify the vendor name (store name, not the user name) by filters just like wordpress filters:

```
function modify_name( $display_name ) {
    return $display_name. '-test';
}
add_filter( 'the_author', 'modify_name', 10, 2 );
```

Is there a filter to do this?
guid me, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **dokan_store_name** filter to modify store name in dokan multivendor plugin.

```
function modify_store_name( $store_name ) {
    return $store_name . '-test';
}
add_filter( 'dokan_store_name', 'modify_store_name', 10, 1 );
```